# In javascript get the value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am populating values in drop down from the database. The every text have values. I want to select the values using JavaScript..

**My code**

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("Role", ViewData["Role"] as SelectList,"Select" , new {onchange = "javascript:ddlRoleChanged();", id="ddlRoles",  @class = "dropdownStyle2"})%>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var tempDDVal = '<%= Session["Function"] %>';
        $("#ddlRoles option:contains(" + tempDDVal + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
    function ddlRoleChanged() {
        debugger;
        var selectvalue = document.getElementById('#ddlRoles');
        var selectedValue = $('#ddlRoles').val();
        window.location = '/home?func=' + selectedValue.valueOf();
    };        
</script>
```

But `selectedvalue` is showing only the text values.. How to take that?

Comment: no need of doing `selectedValue.valueOf()` as you're getting value already!

Comment: i am getting the dropdown showing values only. if i am showing my dropdown green, red, yellow means, my database having the value of green is 1 or red is 2 like that. i wnat to show up the 1, 2 values..

Answer (score 0):

You want the selected item from `#ddlRoles`. Try this:

```
var selectedValue = $('#ddlRoles option:selected').val();
window.location = '/home?func=' + selectedValue;
```

Comment: eg: If i select green option, it have the value 1. i want to select 1 in that selected value

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('#Dropdown').change(function(){
     var DropdownValue = jQuery(this).children('option:selected').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

put your values in data property on your ELEMENT.

```
$("ELEMENT").attr('data-value', 'MYDATA');
```

and after you can get it

```
$("ELEMENT").attr('data-value');
```